# Prove a group is $p$-divisible for a prime $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am wondering how to prove that a finite $G$ with no elements of order $p$ for some prime $p$ implies that $G$ is $p$-divisible. I am a bit confused with how to approach this. It seems to be very related to Cauchy's Theorem. A couple observations: A Group is $n$-divisible iff the automorphism $g\to g^k$ is a surjection.

Maybe this helps?

Comment: Can you solve the problem for, say, cyclic groups?

Comment: $g\mapsto g^k$ is not an automorphism (in general) although it is a perfectly good *function*. And anyways, automorphisms are surjective by definition.

Comment: @JacobManaker This is what I have been told to do. Ive been told if I show that each abelian subgroup of G is p-divisible then so is G. Im confused with how this is true.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson: Any $x\in G$ generates a cyclic subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no elements of order $p$, the order of the finite group $|G|$ is co-prime with $p$ (that is a corollary of Cauchy's theorem and the definition of prime numbers).

Take any $1\ne a\in G$. Then the order $|a|=m$ divides $|G|$ by Lagrange theorem, hence it is co-prime with $p$.

So for some integers $u,v$ we have $um+vp=1$. Hence $a=a^{um+vp}=a^{mu}(a^v)^p=(a^v)^p$. So $a$ has a root of degree $p$, namely $a^v$. So $G$ is $p$-divisible.

Comment: Cauchy theorem was mentioned in OP. Lagrange theorem is studied usually before Cauchy. Calling either of them high powered is an exaggeration.